# Get an input validator from a form object in zf2

Tags: zend-framework2

I have the following input filter:

```
'term' => array(
                'required' => false,
                'filters' => array(
                        array(
                            'name' => 'StringTrim',
                    )
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                    'name' => 'StringLength',
                    'options' => array(
                            'max' => 128
                    )
                  )
                )
            ),
```

I need to get programmatically from a form object the value of the 'max' option inside the 'validators' property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$vc = $form->getInputFilter()->get('term')->getValidatorChain()->getValidators();

foreach($vc as $v){
    if($v['instance'] instanceof \Zend\Validator\StringLength)
        $max = $v['instance']->getMax();
}
```

Comment: You should add a bit more information why this is the answer.

Comment: @MrTux i believe that the code speaks for it self and there is nothing obscure about this code to provide any information

Comment: The answer is absolutely correct but I am surprised as why there is not a simple method available to check if the element has such a `validator` and then get the `max` value out of it.

Comment: @KunalDethe probably because the validators are not meant to be used like that,they meant to `validate` on input not ask the input what validator you have